# How to capture screenshot for certain commands on linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, command-line, screenshot

I have Linux(Ubuntu, Centos) systems, I need to capture screenshot for each of the below command output and same need to be stored in `$HOME/screenshot/`path.

Is it possible via (Mobaxterm) ssh terminal using shell script? As i have many systems therefore script method which is equivalent to the `print screen` option will be helpful.

```
ls -al /etc/passwd
ls -al /etc/group
ls -al /etc/shadow
cat /etc/passwd
cat /etc/profile
ls -al /etc/hosts
ls -al /etc/services
ls -l /usr/bin/last
ls -al /etc/profile
```

Comment: Why would you want textual output as images? Why not simply redirect to a (text) file? `( ls -al /etc/passwd; ... ) > $HOME/screenshot/my_output 2>&1` ?

Comment: It needs for external customer audit purposes.

Comment: but especially then you want text output that can be audited.....

Comment: true, as part of corporate policy, it was decided to share only output screenshots.

Comment: Why don't you just run the commands, redirect their output to a file and take a screenshot of the file?

Comment: Corporate policy makers need to be made aware of tools like [tripwire](https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source), which automatically detect and send alerts on changes to specified files.   Also, use [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/), so that all files under /etc are kept in a version control system like git - changes can be seen with git sub-commands like status, show, and diff.  Both of these are available as ubuntu packages.

Comment: Ok I will share this information with our security policy team.

Answer (score 0):

`import -window $WINDOW -compress JPEG "screenshot.jpg"` where $WINDOW is either window id obtained for example from `wmctrl` or you can use `root` for whole desktop. `import` is part of ImageMagick package, see man page for more info.

Comment: On putty terminal tried the following. `1) ls -l`  `2) import -window root -compress JPEG "screenshot.jpg"`  3) copied the `screenshot.jpg` to my windows system `4) On my windows it shows black screenshot`

Comment: You said you had Linux, so I silently assumed you were working on it. The command takes a screenshot from your X session. It obviously wouldn't work over Putty. If you want screenshot of Putty, you would have to automate it somehow in Windows.

Comment: Oh I m sorry I didn't shared before the way I m trying. ok thanks for the information. Yes I have many systems in our Lab. Currently accessing them using mobaxterm(Putty).

Comment: @Kishore mobaxterm is NOT Putty. If you want a screenshot of a Windows program, your question is not related to Unix.

Comment: We connect our Linux systems using Mobaxterm from our windows. I m looking some script to capture the output of above given commands in Linux.

Comment: You can't take screenshots of your window on your Windows from the Linux computer you ssh into. Uless you setup some crazy back VNC mechanism.